# Emulating bluebird.promisifyAll with util.promisify

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to promisify the entire [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) `RedisClient` object using Node 8's `util.promisify` in a manner similar to how Bluebird's `promisifyAll()` works, and not having much luck.

This is what I've tried thus far:

```
import * as _redis from 'redis';
import { promisify } from 'util';
const client = _redis.createClient();
const redis = Object.keys(client).reduce((c, key) => {
  if (typeof c[key] === 'function') c[key] = promisify(c[key]).bind(c);
  return c;
}, client);
```

This, however, works:

```
const redis = {
  get: promisify(client.get).bind(client),
  set: promisify(client.set).bind(client),
  hget: promisify(client.hget).bind(client),
  hmset: promisify(client.hmset).bind(client),
};
```

Any ideas?

*edit:* The main reason I'm wanting to use `util.promisify` instead of something like Bluebird is because I'm doing this all in TypeScript, and Bluebird's `promisifyAll` doesn't seem to work with that.

Comment: This should help http://grizzlybit.info/2017/09/29/Node-JS-8-Util-Promisify/

Comment: @zubair1024 It doesn't, and your blog post has nothing to do with my actual question. 

Comment: Here's an implementation of `promisifyAll()` using `util.promisify()`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/util-promisifyall

Answer (score 5):

Came across this as I was looking for a same thing. This is what I'm using currently and it seems to work:

```js
const { promisify } = require('util')
const redis = require('redis')

const client = redis.createClient('redis://localhost:6379')

client.promise = Object.entries(redis.RedisClient.prototype)
  .filter(([_, value]) => typeof value === 'function')
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key]: promisify(value).bind(client)
  }), {})

client.on('connect', async () => {
  await client.promise.set('foo', 'bar')

  console.log(await client.promise.get('foo'))
})
```

Comment: This works well, but a small addition to anyone using typescript: combine the filter and reduce into something like this: `reduce((acc, [key, val]) => (typeof val === 'function' ? ({ ...acc, [key]: promisify(val).bind(client) }) : acc), {})`. Otherwise typescript gets unhappy with `promisify(value)`.

Comment: You'll also need to do some funky playing around with types, I ended up with an interface file that re-implements a lot of the Redis types (found here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/redis/index.d.ts ) to make them return promises.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following module, it's very simple to use and can be used to replace bluebird promises. [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/util-promisifyall)

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/util-promisifyall
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [fluentify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluentifyjs), it's tiny and has no external dependencies and pretty much does what your after. I've actually used it myself for Redis, there are some small caveats but in your case should be fairly straightforward e.g.

```
import * as _redis from 'redis';
import fluentify from 'fluentifyjs';
...
const client = fluentify(_redis.createClient());
const result = await client.get('key').done();
```

I get that your probably looking to do this natively, however, thought it'd be worth mentioning as an alternative, considering you'd get method chaining for free if needed.

*Disclaimer - I'm the author*

Comment: Does it work in TypeScript at all? Both in terms of having definition files and being able to pass function signature back to intellisense? A big reason I'm wanting to use native util.promisify is because it works nicely with TypeScript.

Comment: @aendrew unfortunately not, although it wouldn't be too difficult to add support. Think the lib would just need the definition file added, I don't use TypeScript so not really in a position to do it at the moment. If it's something you'd feel comfortable adding support for feel free to create a PR.